# IoC and managing interfaces

Tags: interface, ioc-container, decoupling

Say I had a business object library which was using IoC to implement a data access library. Where should I define the Data Access Interface? Which library does it belong? Or should it be in a separate library just for interfaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define the interfaces within the business domain.  Then the implementations of the interfaces would be in a library that references the business domain (and is referenced by whatever the application context is, or by an IoC library which is referenced by the application context).

Then swapping out one implementation with another is just a matter of creating another library and swapping the reference in the application context.

In a .NET project structure it would look something like this:

> Domain Logic Project
>       (references nothing)
>       Domain Models
>       Repository Interfaces
>       IoC Service Locator Interface
>   Repository Project
>       (References Domain Logic Project)
>       Repository Implementations
>   IoC Project
>       (References Domain Logic Project)
>       (References Repository Project)
>       IoC Service Locator Implementation
>       IoC Bootstrapping
>   Application Project
>       (References IoC Project)
>       (References Domain Logic Project)
>       (May need to reference Repository Project, not sure)
>       Implements UI which interacts with Domain Models

Comment: What about if the Repository Implementations was being used by two different libraries? Would that would mean two references, two interfaces?

Comment: @g.foley: What else needs to reference the repository implementations besides the IoC container?  Everything would reference the domain logic (interfaces) and code to that.  Then any given application context would reference the domain logic and the IoC to call the bootstrapper to wire it all up.

Comment: @g.foley: Or do you mean that there are two domain logic projects, and a single repository project implements the repositories for both?  In that case, referencing both shouldn't be a problem.  But it would likely result in any given application context carrying the DLLs for both domains, if it only needs one.  But the bulk of logic should be in the domains, which don't reference each other.  So in general you should be good, you'd just have tag-along DLLs.

Comment: @g.foley: The repository implementations can reference and implement all the interfaces they want, now that I picture it more.  In fact, there's nothing stopping you from having one giant implementing class which implements all repository interfaces in every domain you have.  It's kind of silly, but it's allowed.  The abstractions and separation of concerns are in the interfaces.  The implementation is of less concern because it should be disposable/replaceable.